# asp.net control for displaying data in a grid

Tags: asp.net, controls, grid

I'm attempting to build a page that displays the same set of information of different "items" in a grid or table. It's akin to a shopping page that displays products in for e.g. a 4 by 3 table.

I came across datagrid and gridview but they display grouped information according to columns and each row representing one item only.

Is there a control that displays data in a very basic grid format instead of tabular form, preferably with built in pagination abilities?

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will want to use a `DataList` or a `Repeater`, as those controls allow you to specify the exact HTML you want for each item.  Unfortunately, neither of those have built in pagination, but honestly, the built in pagination in the `GridView` is of questionable usefulness, since it only works if you use a specific data source or load everything from the database up front.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean, you want a basic grid, but gridview doesn't work for you. But in any case, check out the repeater. It will require a bit more work to built a template for your items, but it's very flexible and can handle what you want.

Comment: thanks! I got it working with your suggested control and built the pagination portion from scratch